# How safe are things stored in memory?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

Let's say I have a program that reads a file into memory and uses something (e.g. rijndael/AES) to decrypt it. How protected is the new unencrypted stream/string/whatever that my program is holding in memory? I realize that it would take a bit of memory trickery to even attempt it, but I'm just curious. I don't know a lot about how programming/stack/memory works in relation to .NET/VS2010 so I apologize. On that note, how safe are hard-coded strings (e.g. the connection string to a SQL server that would contain a user/pw made for the software)?

Comment: It's just as secure or insecure as any other sensitive data you have or use on your computer at runtime, because those things are realized through applications and memory too. At some point everything, as you say, is unencrypted in memory if it's being used by the application or understood by the end-user. What I'm saying is I think this question isn't specific to .NET/VS2010, especially not C# because that's a syntax - you might want to use the [CIL] tag instead.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language

Comment: Even if you encrypted your connection strings, it should still be rather trivial to catch them via either packet sniffing or DLL injection or whatever. Bottom line: Never give people direct access to your database, put a web service or something inbetween.

Answer (score 4):

Not safe at all, even with Memory Protection it's trivial to just take a memory dump or use something like [Crack.net](http://cracknetproject.codeplex.com/) to peek into memory.

You can use [System.Security.SecureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring.aspx) which is a bit painful to work with but "Represents text that should be kept confidential. The text is encrypted for privacy when being used, and deleted from computer memory when no longer needed."

Comment: Indeed, as said, SecureString is a pain to work with and requires full end-to-end usage (as opposed to converting between SecureString and String which completely defeats the purpose)

Answer (score 1):

Hard-coded strings are not safe at all.  It is a trivial matter to extract all the strings from an .exe file.

In-memory is quite a bit safer.  Modern Operating Systems have a lot of memory protection, to prevent one process from reading/modifying the memory of another.  This would prevent spyware from reading a password from the memory segment of another process.

As long as your process only holds the unencrypted value in memory (never writes it to a file, transmits it, stores it in a database, etc), it is probably safe enough.

For super-secret data, you have to care about warm-reboots.  This is when your program holds the unencrypted data in memory, then the user reboots the machine, and proceeds to read all of main memory.  In such a scenario, it is possible for the memory to still contain the unencrypted information.  However, this is kinda extreme, and (for most applications) not worth worrying about.

To sum up:

- unencrypted data in memory = ok
- unencrypted data hard-coded in .exe file = bad

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep strings loaded into memory safe, use the SecureString class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring.aspx.  See also: http://www.vcskicks.com/secure-string.php

Answer (score 0):

Without using a specialized API, you should assume that any text in memory is readable by anyone that can read your hard disk, and anyone that can read you process memory (e.g. root or equivalent, another process from the same user, or an exploit within your process).

Your memory may be paged to disk.  Certain environments have specialized ways of allocating memory that prevents paging (I don't know if such a facility is available from the C# standard libraries, but I assume one is available for use on Windows).

Comment: Is there any alternative to prompting the user for credentials for the SQL server? I don't really want the end-user to know that information either, so I'd prefer to hard-code the SQL connection string in the program. Though, seeing crack.net makes me concerned somebody could easily pull that string. Maybe this is out of the scope of my program, and I should just say "we should audit that account's db connections", but that feels like a cop out.

Comment: @Jeff Plott, I don't know too much about SQL Server in particular so I'm not really qualified to give you advice there.  But if your problem is authentication, then generally speaking, yes, there are several alternatives to demanding a user name and password.  One example is Kerberos.